# How to build an application with TypeScript?

Tags: meteor, typescript

How do you build a Meteor application with TypeScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is this github project : https://github.com/grmlin/meteor-typescript

Comment: I guess this is the only resource so far.

Comment: looks liks this hasn't been updated in awhile

Comment: an alternative to this would be https://github.com/meteor-typescript/meteor-typescript-compiler

Comment: The updated Typescript package can be found here: https://github.com/barbatus/typescript

Answer (score 23):

Please add meteor typescript compiler to your project. it compiles .ts artifacts on the fly using the tsc command line (batch mode)

The package source is available [via GitHub](https://github.com/orefalo/meteor-typescript-compiler). You may also add the plugin  directly by typing `meteor add meteortypescript:compiler` from your project root directory.

Comment: There's no prefix here, so that implies that the package is by MDG, but there's no such package from MDG. From the GitHub link, I think that you meant `meteor add meteortypescript:compiler`.